# CSS3 animation rotate direction - select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to give rotate direction to my custom select-box, that should completing 1-TURN or complete cycle. if open it should clockwise while closing again clockwise.

This is what I have tried : 
`http://codepen.io/iahmad/pen/qNvaQr`

direction will always be like this
`http://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/120/120869.png`

Answer (score 2):

With simple alternations to your jQuery script, you could achieve your desired effect by the following logic:

- Default state of img is 0 rotation
- On click, apply the class `open` which adds rotation of 180 degrees.
- When clicking again, another class is added `.turn` which completes the rotation cycle to 360 degrees.
- When `turn` finishes transition (after 1 second), we remove all classes to restore rotation to 0, however the transition from 360 to 0 will be problematic, so to avoid this we temporarily disable the transition and restore it again on the next click.

Demo:

```js
$(function(){
  $('a').on('click', function(){
    var el = $(this);
    if (!el.hasClass('open')) {
      el.children('img').attr('style','');
      el.addClass('open');
    } else {
      el.removeClass('open').addClass('turn');
      setTimeout(function(){ 
       el.children('img').attr('style','transition: none');
        el.removeClass('turn');
      }, 1000); 
    }
  });
});
```

```css
a img { transition: all 1s ease; }
a.open img { transform: rotate(180deg); }
a.turn img  { transform: rotate(360deg); }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#"><img src="http://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/118/118738.png"></a>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/zcnatgxq/

Comment: Might be helpful to add that this leads to some weirdness if the user interrupts the animation in the middle.